# Smartphone 3D Capabilities Database

Tags: mobile, 3d

Is there a website or downloadable document that contains information about the 3D capabilities (Fillrate, Features, Shader Units etc) of the 3D Hardware used in many of today's smartphones such as IPhone 3G, IPhone 4, the more popular Android Devices, Windows Phone 7 etc?

Answer (score 1):

If a resource like this existed that sure would have saved me a lot of time! Back when I first started my current job, my first task was to make a spreadsheet of information about the 3D capabilities of all the smartphones out there. It was waaaay harder than I expected, because the various device manufacturers are surprisingly cagey about specific info other than what's in their marketing brochures. I didn't even get every device out there (just a solid sampling of the best known ones) nor did I investigate them to quite the depth you're asking for.

In general however I found a few common patterns and most useful resources that, taken together, told me most of what I needed to know.

First off, pretty much all the smartphones out there use either a PowerVR chip or a Qualcomm chip (formerly/alternatively known as "Adreno"; it's a long story, read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adreno#Renaming_to_Adreno)) for the GPU. For example, all iPhones use a PowerVR GPU (different generations though) and Microsoft has mandated that all WinPhone 7 devices use the exact same Snapdragon chipset from Qualcomm. Motorola Droids use PowerVR, HTC Android phones use Qualcomm, etc.

Second, I relied heavily on the sites GLBenchmark, PDAdb.net, and good ole Wikipedia. For example, going to the "Results" tab on GLBenchmark brings up a list of all the smartphones they've tested, then go the the iPhone 3Gs results, and then go to the "GL Environment" tab:

http://www.glbenchmark.com/phonedetails.jsp?benchmark=glpro20&D=Apple+iPhone+3G+S&testgroup=gl

Oh hey look, it has a PowerVR SGX 535